# Overwritting onclick with page onload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this link  that activates  a voice recorder in my site but I would like to activate that onclick function on page load.

I tried using this solution but did not work how can I go about loading the onclick function on page load please help. the code is below:

```
    <div id="control_panel">
    <a id="record_button" onClick="Recorder.record('audio', 'audio.wav');" href="javascript:void  (0);" title="Record"><img src="images/record.png" width="24" height="24"      alt="Record"/><!--</a>-->
     <span id="save_button">
      <span id="flashcontent">
      <p>Your browser must have JavaScript enabled and the Adobe Flash Player installed.</p>
       </span>
       </span>
       <a id="play_button" style="display:none;" onclick="Recorder.playBack('audio');" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Play"><img src="images/play.png" width="24" height="24" alt="Play"/></a>
      </div>
```

tried all the possible solutions you came up with but now its giving me the bottom message though I would like this to just record on page load please help guys.

here is the message: Your browser must have JavaScript enabled and the Adobe Flash Player installed

Comment: Why not just call `Recorder.record('audio', 'audio.wav');` ?

Comment: A better solution would be code reuse. You want to run the same code from `$("#record_button").click` and `$(document).ready`. Put the code you want to run in a function and handle both events with the same function.

Comment: Yucky onClick event. You can also remove that, and in your document ready function use .delegate() or even .click() to bind the event properly even if you're going to fire it automatically.

Comment: Greg I have done the delegate but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to fix this problem is to completely separate out your HTML and JavaScript code.  Then you can simply invoke the click handler directly on load

HTML:

```
<a id="record_button" title="Record">...</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var record = function() {
    Recorder.record('audio', 'audio.wav');
  };

  // Bind the 'record' action to the link.  
  $('#record_button').click(function(event) {
    record();
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  // Start it on page load
  record();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VRB5H/

Comment: I would pass the event into the click function, call event.preventDefault(), and remove the 'return false'... but other than that, this is what I had in mind, too.

Comment: @GregPettit see my most recent edits.  Had the exact same thought after I posted and quickly editted to that solution.

Comment: Jared thanks man but the function is not invoking the onclick function nothing

Comment: @user1004577 sorry there was a typo in the code.  I just updated it and added a fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like that, but you'll need to make sure Recorder.record() is valid, of course.

```
<a id="record_button" href="#" title="Record">a#record_button</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#record_button').click(Recorder.record('audio', 'audio.wav'));
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Wayne thanks dude but hey this function gives me an error though would be glad to give you the page source if thats fine with you to look at it I have been looking and trying many solutions in this but only ur function seems to make a difference in this case

Comment: Pumba, a page source is always useful in such cases. Like I mentioned in my original answer, Recorder.record() has to be valid, and so far I've not seen any JavaScript API that can do this, you see. It seems like Flash ActionScript already has a mature API to do such things. IMO, that is more appropriate anyways: http://livedocs.adobe.com/fms/2/docs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000550.html